# How can my code react to unexpected inputs in c++?

Tags: c++

Newbe so please don't be to harsh, I'll try to explain my problem as well as possible.

I have a longer code, that receives 0, 1, or n, arguments as input.
These inputs are supposed to be strings, however if I run my program like this:
./task2 ^!..;:
I simply get:
bash: !..: event not found

how can I prevent this error, and just print an error message?

This is task2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

/// Build suffix array from text.
/// Input is an emtpy suffix array and the text.
/// Output is a suffix array (sorted).
void construct(std::vector<uint32_t>& sa, const std::string& text)
{
    if(text.empty()) {
        cout << "Text is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (sa.size()!=0) {
        sa.clear();
    }

    for (uint32_t a = 0; a<text.length(); ++a) {
        sa.push_back(a);
    }

    sort(sa.begin(),sa.end(),[&text] (uint32_t s1, uint32_t s2) {
    return(text.substr(s1)<=text.substr(s2));
    });
    return;
}


//Wir brauchen kein $ am Ende unseres Strings, da wir keinen Suffixbaum aufbauen und wir somit nicht das Problem haben
//werden, dass ein Suffix ein Prefix eines aderen Suffix ist. 

/// search for a 'query' string in a suffix array 'sa' build from 'text'.
/// Results are returned in 'hits'.

void findmlr(uint32_t& mlr, const uint32_t L, const uint32_t R, const std::string& query, const std::vector<uint32_t>& sa, const std::string& text) {
    uint32_t mlrl = mlr;
    uint32_t mlrr = mlr;


    /* for L */
    for(uint32_t l = mlr; l<query.size(); ++l) {
        if (query[mlr] == text[sa[L]+mlrl]) {
            mlrl+=1;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }

    /* for R */
    for(uint32_t r = mlr; r<query.size(); ++r) {
        //cout << query[mlr] << text[sa[R]+mlrr] << endl;
        if (query[mlr] == text[sa[R]+mlrr]) {
            mlrr+=1;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }

    mlr = min(mlrl,mlrr);
    return;
}


void find(std::vector<uint32_t>& hits, const std::string& query, const std::vector<uint32_t>& sa, const std::string& text){


    if(hits.size()!=0) {
    hits.clear();
    }

    if (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cout << "unexpected input" << endl;
    }

    if (text.size()==0) {
        cout << "text is empty";
        return;
    }

    else if (query.size()==0) {
        cout << "query is empty";
        return;
    }


    /* finding Lp */
    uint32_t Lp;
    if (query <= text.substr(sa[0])){ 
            Lp = 0;
    }

    else if (query > text.substr(sa[text.length()-1])){
            Lp = text.length();
    }

    else { 
        uint32_t L = 0;
        uint32_t R = text.length()-1;
        uint32_t mlr = 0;
        while (R-L > 1) {


                uint32_t M = ceil((L+R)/2);

                findmlr(mlr,L,R,query,sa,text);

                if (query.substr(mlr) <= (text.substr(sa[M]+mlr))) {
                    R = M;
                }
                else {
                    L = M;
                }
        }
        Lp = R;
    }

    for (uint32_t i = Lp; i < text.length(); ++i) {
        if ((text.substr(sa[i])).substr(0,query.length()) == query) {
            if(find(hits.begin(), hits.end(), sa[i]) != hits.end()){
                //do nothing
            } 
            else{
            hits.push_back(sa[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
             break;
        }
    }

    sort(hits.begin(), hits.end());
    return;
}
```

and this is task2_main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include "aufgabe2.hpp"
#include <stdint.h>
//#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

if (argc < 2){
    cout << "not enough arguments were given" << endl;
    return 1;}

if (argc == 2){

    vector<uint32_t> sa;
    string input_string(argv[1]);
    construct(sa,input_string);

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i<input_string.length(); ++i) {
        cout << sa[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
    }

if (argc > 2){
    vector<uint32_t> hits;
    string text(argv[1]);
    vector<uint32_t> sa;

    if (sa.size() != 0) {
        sa.clear();
    }
    if (hits.size() != 0) {
        hits.clear();
    }

    int z;
    z = 2;
        while(z < argc){
            /*
            if(typeid(argv[z])!=typeid(text)) {
                cout << typeid(text).name() << z << " is not of type string" << endl;
            }
            */

            if (sa.size()!=0) {
            sa.clear();
            }


                for (int unsigned a = 0; a<text.length(); ++a)
                {
                sa.push_back(a);
                }
                sort(sa.begin(),sa.end(),[&text] (uint32_t s1, uint32_t s2) {
                return(text.substr(s1)<=text.substr(s2));
                });

            string query(argv[z]);
            string input_string(argv[1]);

            if (query.size() == 0) {
                //do nothing
            }
            else if (input_string.size() == 0) {
                //do nothing
            }
            else {
            cout << (argv[z]) << ":";
            }

            find(hits,query,sa,input_string);

                for (uint32_t i = 0; i < hits.size(); ++i) {
                cout << " " << hits[i];
                }

            cout << endl;
            ++z;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do show your code. In case it is long the relevant portion. :)

Comment: `I have a longer code` Can we see some of this long code? Otherwise, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please copy,paste your code so that we can help.

Comment: I have included the code. Why did I get downvoted already?

Comment: you need to put the arguments in quotes on the command line `./task2 "^!..;:"` - bash is trying to interpret the character you typed as things it understands

Comment: you have the code. that does not work either. also not putting valid strings in quotes still works.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your C++ code. It’s the shell (bash in your case) interpreting exclamation sign as command history reference. Simple solution - quote those arguments with single quotes (like `’arg'`) .

Comment: nice. I thought that my be it, but none of my friend could confirm it. still the task clarifies that there might be an invalid input, which we need an exception for, and I don't know what counts as "invalid input"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bash event not found" is completely external to your program; GNU Bash has a (mis)feature whereby it reacts to the `!` character in a command line, even if that character is in a double-quote.

```
$ echo "blah!blah!"
bash: !blah!: event not found
$ echo 'blah!blah!'
blah!blah!
```

Note that in the first case, `echo` is not even called; Bash failed to process the command line as such, and `echo` was never invoked. If you see this message, your program is not being called at all and so the situation doesn't speak to how your program handles any kind of input.

You have to escape the `!` with single quotes or a backslash.  What Bash is trying to do here is to look for `blah` in the command history for a command which begins with `blah` and substitute it. This is "history expansion".

The feature is fully described under `HISTORY EXPANSION` in the Bash manual page.

Comment: thank you very much. We are still asked to include an exception for invalid inputs that prints unexpected input. Right now I can't think of another place to put it, then the case that you entered 0 arguments.

Comment: @DanielGießing Right; just in the case "event not found", your program is not being called at all. Bash has failed to process the command line as such.  So that situation doesn't demonstrate anything about the behavior of your program.